# Finding specific positive integer

Tags: java

I want to find the integer, n, so that there are 1000 combinations when 1/z + 1/x = 1/n. This is my code:

```
int counter = 0;
    double n = 1;

    while (true) {
        for (double i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
            for (double t = 1; t < 10000; t++) {
                if ((1/i) + (1/t) == (1/n)) {                       
                    counter++;
                    System.out.println(counter);
                }
            }           
        }   
        if (counter < 1000) {
            counter = 0;
            n++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Counterr: " + counter);
            System.out.println("Answer: " + n);
            System.exit(0);
        } 
    }
```

It works if  I try to find 4 combinations, but not when 1000. Why?

Comment: I assume that "it doesn't work" means "it doesn't terminate" right?

Comment: Also, this highly resemble a Project Euler problem (that I remember doing). Can't find it but I will and Project Euler is about finding yourself the solution. Found it https://projecteuler.net/problem=108 There's his little brother https://projecteuler.net/problem=110 that _much_ more complicated.

Comment: ...ran your code for five minutes, got n up to 200 and the highest combination I saw was 59 combos. You may think about visiting the Stack Exchange for Math or consider that there is no such number.

Comment: @Justen The solution is much greater than 200. But there is one :).

Comment: @Tunaki I figured there was, I simply meant to illustrate, like you said, that  this solution is not really feasable based on the amount of time it took just to get to 200

Comment: I have not gotten any helpful answers. Is my entire code badly written simply due to the extreme amount of time required?

Comment: You guys are going about this wrong. Here are some hints: (1) use the proper datatypes. (2) use optimizations. Look at the original formula and it is staring right at you.  (3) using #2, alter the formula

Comment: Never use a double as the loop variable in a for loop.  Never.  You will get accumulation errors as you add the loop increment to the loop value.

Comment: are you looking to find the first n where there are *at least* 1000 combinations or exactly 1000 combinations? When the routine is written more properly, the first one can be found in 100ms on a mediocre laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because of floating point precision issues. You use increment `++` operator on double within a loop and compare doubles by `==`. Result of those operations may be not as expected, especially after many iterations.

Try changing your code to work with integers with exact precision, not doubles. Note that your equation

> 1/z + 1/x = 1/n

is equivalent to

> n * (x + z) = x * z

So, change your loop as follows:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
        for (int t = 1; t < 10000; t++) {
            if (n * (i + t) == i * t) {
                counter++;
                System.out.println(counter);
            }
        }           
    }
```

Also, there is now more clear how to optimize your iteration ranges. Think about lower and upper limits for `i` and `t` - reducing iteration ranges will improve overall performance significantly.

Unfortunately, I didn't tested the result at the moment, but I'm pretty sure you should do calculations in integers, not in doubles.

Answer (score -1):

You did not provide a error code that pops up in Netbeans. But i'm assuming there is a outofbounds error. or exception error. It cannot find 1000 because your while loop is infinite. You must be able to stop the loop when "combinations" hits 1000

Comment: It does stop the loop if hitting 1000...

Answer (score -1):

Try increasing the search space by using a higher number than `10000` in your inner loops. Maybe `9999999` ?

I believe is highly unlikely that you find 1000 combinations of `1/z + 1/x = 1/n` for the same `n` with `{z,x,n} in [1...10000]`.

Edit.

```
int counter = 0;
    double n = 1;
    double maxiter = 1000*1000;
    double i,t;
    while (true) {
        for (i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
            for (t = 1; t < 10000; t++) {
                if ((1/i) + (1/t) == (1/n)) {                       
                    counter++;
                    System.out.println(counter);
                }
            }           
        }
        if (i*t == maxiter) break; 
        if (counter < 1000) {
            counter = 0;
            n++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Counterr: " + counter);
            System.out.println("Answer: " + n);
            System.exit(0);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't terminate, just tested.